# using height 100vh goes far beyond browser window

Tags: css

i've been reading on "height 100vh" and how it makes the div 100% in height and shrinks according to browser window. Now in my case the div goes beyond the browser window.

is it posibble to make that div stop at my footer div at the bottom?

Comment: Please include your CSS. If there is a horizontal scrollbar, 100vh will be more than the available height.

Comment: @Shikkediel there is no horizontal scrollbar :/ it still goes beyond browser window :/

Comment: do you have `meta` tag for `viewport`? also check this for compatibility - http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Sounds like something trivial but we'd need to see the code or a live link.

Comment: @RobScott no, should i?

Comment: Sounds like a missing reset css - http://jsfiddle.net/j899f92p/

Comment: Likely indeed, meta tag should be unrelated to using viewport units.

Comment: Also `100vh` **doesn't** mean 100% of the **remaining** height, so if you footer comes after this div...it will be offscreen

Comment: Are you trying to do this? - http://jsfiddle.net/j899f92p/2/

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you very much :) didnt think of using calc for this :)