# Element with height: 100vh covers horizontal scrollbar

Tags: css

My page scrolls horizontally on large screens. I have an `<nav>` element set to `position: fixed` and `height: 100vh`.

The problem is the `<nav>` is outside(?) of the viewport and is on top of the horizontal scrollbar (making it difficult to scroll!). See screenshot and code example below.

[image: height: 100vh element covering horizontal scrollbar]

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-site-title, .site-description {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 1rem;
}

nav {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 111, 0.81);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 225px;
}

.main-content-list {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 1211px;
  padding-left:225px;
}

.main-content-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.image-item {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: initial;
}
  
.image-item img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav>
  <h1 class="main-site-title">Site Title</h1>
  <p class="site-description">Nav goes here.</p>
</nav>

<article>
  <ul class="main-content-list">
    <li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li><li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li><li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li><li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li><li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

Possibly related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628221/using-height-100vh-goes-far-beyond-browser-window), but I'm not sure. I'd like the scrollbar to be usable and to know why this happens.

Comment: With `position: fixed`, you've removed `nav` from the normal flow. That means there's nothing in the `body` element occupying any space. (Or maybe this, but we can't tell from the limited code provided in the question.) Consider adding `height:100vh` to the `body` element.

Comment: I understand that ```position: fixed``` removed the ```nav``` from the normal flow, it's actually my intent here. However, I wouldn't expect the ```nav``` to flow outside of the viewport (that is, assuming the viewport doesn't include scrollbars???).

Comment: Post enough code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Michael_B Sorry, I should have posted some code with my original question. Here is something that I threw together as an example: https://jsfiddle.net/soaby3jp/3/show/

Comment: Lots of posts on Stack about this issue. In case you've missed them, [here's a list](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=css%20position%20fixed%20over%20scrollbar).

Comment: @Michael_B OK, thanks. I did search around a little but I think I was thrown by the ```height: 100vh``` set on my ```<nav>``` element. I didn't realize that this was such a common issue. After reading some of your links I still don't understand why this occurs. Is it part of the spec or a bug? Oh well, I guess I will hack my way around this with ```height: calc(100vh - 16px)```. (I found that idea one of the links you sent on the Google search results page).

Comment: It may be neither a bug or in the spec. Could just be browser implementation. Also, I am familiar with the `calc` method, but I didn't recommend it because different browsers have different scrollbar widths. If you're okay with possible imprecision on occasion, that method could work.

Comment: @Michael_B It's a risk I'll have to run, I guess.

Comment: Make sure to check your layout in iOS devices. I think Safari in particular has a much narrower scrollbar.

Comment: @Michael_B Roger that! I'm only using this layout on breakpoints closer to a desktop computer screen size. Or, did you mean that Safari on Mac desktop has a much more narrow scrollbar than most desktop browsers? Hmm... Will have to find a Mac to test on.. Thanks again! : )

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to add `overflow-x: auto` to the root element (html).
https://jsfiddle.net/soaby3jp/5/

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.main-site-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2rem;
}

nav {
  background: rgba(0, 255, 111, 0.81);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 300px;
}

.main-content-list {
  white-space: nowrap;
  /*overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;*/ /* put these to the root element (html) */
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 1211px;
  padding-left: 300px;
}

.main-content-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

img {
  width: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.image-item {
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: initial;
}
  
html {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1 class="main-site-title">Test for SO</h1>
</nav>

<article>
  <ul class="main-content-list">
    <li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li><li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li><li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li><li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li><li class="image-item"><img src="https://placekitten.com/1500/1000"></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- /.main-content-list -->
</article>
```

Comment: The scrollbar does show now using ```z-index: -1```, so I'll give you an upvote but using z-index has a caveat of removing the effect I was going for with ```position: fixed``` (see my recently added code example). You answered my question, but now I have another issue. I have to figure out a way to make the ```<nav>``` stay in the same place and be visible. 

**I still don't understand why the ```<nav>``` element seems to break outside of the viewport (and end up on top of the scrollbar).**

Comment: The problem is that when using viewport (vw, vh), it relies on the visible area of the browser, so when adding the fixed position on the nav it takes it out of the natural flow of the page. ---

Comment: So maybe it would be possible to do this using only percentage instead of vh. But a simpler fix would be to put the scroll bar elsewhere, like say the root element. I have updated the answer with it.